# How to automatically build sub-project when main-project is built?

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I am working with Apache Netbeans IDE and I am using Gradle as build system for my Java application. My project consists of a main project containing some GUI code and a sub library project.

I want that my sub library project automatically compiles when my main project is built. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Here's the gradle file of my main project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'ch.minibot32.Launcher'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('../MiniBot32Lib/build/libs/MiniBot32Lib.jar')
    compile 'uk.co.electronstudio.sdl2gdx:sdl2gdx:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.glazedlists:glazedlists:1.11.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'res'
        }
    }
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ch.minibot32.Launcher'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

task createFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'ch.minibot32.Launcher'
    }
    baseName = 'MiniBot32-Release'
    from { 
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}
```

Here's the gradle file of my sub library project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }
}
```

---

### Update A

When using the supposed command from Eng.Fouad I get the following error:

```
> Project with path ':MiniBot32Lib' could not be found in root project 'MiniBot32'.
```

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
Netbeans_Projects
 |_ MiniBot32           <- Main Project          
 |   |_ build
 |   |_ src
 |   |_ build.gradle
 |   |_ settings.gradle
 |_ MiniBot32Lib        <- Sub Project
     |_ build
     |_ src
     |_ build.gradle
     |_ settings.gradle
```

---

### Update B

Additionally I had to add the following to `settings.gradle` after the `rootProject` definition:

```
include ':MiniBot32Lib'
project(':MiniBot32Lib').projectDir = new File('../MiniBot32Lib')
```

Thank you Eng.Fouad !

Comment: You want your sub library project automatically compiles when your main project is built, even if the compilation of your sub library is up to date ?

Comment: @ToYonos: Currently I have to manually compile the sub project everytime I change something in this sub project (the main project does currently not automatically compile the sub project even if I have changed something within the sub project). If there's a way to always automatically compile the sub project when compiling the main project, this would also be fine. However, only compiling if something had changed would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
implementation files('../MiniBot32Lib/build/libs/MiniBot32Lib.jar')
```

with

```
implementation project(":MiniBot32Lib")
```

which makes the sub-project as a dependency that is built upon building the main project.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried your suggested approach, but I am getting a gradle error. It doesn't find the sub project. How do I have to define the path correctly? I added some more information to my original post (section "update"). Thanks!

Comment: @salocinx I think you are missing the file `settings.gradle` that should declare and include both of sub-projects `MiniBot32` and `MiniBot32Lib`. See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:defining_common_behavior

Comment: @salocinx Note that there should be only one `settings.gradle` in multi-project setup.

Comment: Great! Now it's working perfectly :-D Thank you so much for your help. I will give you the bounty in 18 hrs (stackoverflow says I have to wait for this additional time until I can award the bounty to you). I updated my original post with the final adjustments I had to make according to your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @salocinx I am glad that I could help.

Comment: Bounty awarded. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it.